# Finding the shortest distance from the origin to this curve

Tags: calculus, parametric

> Find the shortest distance between the origin point and the curve 
>   \begin{align*}
> x&=2\sin t - \sin 2t\\
> y&=2\cos t - \cos 2t
> \end{align*}

I don't even know how to draw this curve, help please.

Comment: Start with some test points, what is $(x,y)$ when $t=0, \pi,  2 \pi , ...$.

Comment: The curve looks like [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric%20plot%20(2%20sin%20t%20-%20sin%202t,%202%20cos%20t%20-%20cos%202t)), but you don't need to know that. You just need to [evaluate the distance](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify%20sqrt((2%20sin%20t%20-%20sin%202t)%5E2%20%2B%20(2%20cos%20t%20-%20cos%202t)%5E2)) $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ as a function of $t$ and find its minimum.

Comment: @Kaynex i tried that but dx/dt  = 0  therefore dy/dx = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimising the distance to a ppoint of the curve is also minimising the *square* of this distance:
\begin{align}
d^2(t)&=(2\sin t-\sin 2t)^2+(2\cos t-\cos 2t)^2=4+1-4(\sin t\sin 2t+\cos t\cos 2t)\\
&=5-4\cos(2t- t)=5-4\cos t.
\end{align}
So the minimum is $d=1$ (and the maximum is $d=9$).

Answer (score 1):

HINT: the  distance is given by
$$\sqrt{(2\sin(t)-\sin(2t))^2+(2\cos(t)-\cos(2t))^2}$$
simplifying and differentiating with respect to $t$ gives
$$\sqrt{5-4\cos(t)}$$ and the derivative is given by
$$\frac{1}{2}(5-4\cos(t))^{-1/2}8\sin(t)$$